# How to restore document \baselinestretch to table caption and notes

Tags: tables, captions, longtable, line-spacing, setspace

With a double or onehalf line spaced document with a requirement to have single line spaced tables, how is it possible to retain the document spacing for the table captions and notes?

In the MWE (produced from a pandoc template), which uses the `apa6` class, the `man` class option sets the document at 12pt and with double spacing. By using the `setspace`, `etoolbox` and `caption` packages I have been able to achieve the required result (ignoring spacing above the table caption and below the table notes) by hardcoding the stretch factor at `1.655`, which I found in `setspace.sty` for this combination of font size and line spacing.

However, I am looking for a general solution which is able to restore the line spacing of the table captions and notes to the value of `\baselinestretch` at the beginning of the document. (i.e., whatever the body text line spacing might be is what is applied to the table caption and notes regardless of what the line spacing might be of the table rows).

```
\documentclass[man,floatsintext,noextraspace,longtable,nofontenc,nolmodern,nosf]{apa6}
% man class option sets entire document at 12pt and with double spacing

\usepackage{lipsum}                      % only for MWE

% \usepackage{longtable,threeparttable}  % loaded by apa6
% \usepackage{etoolbox}                  % loaded by apa6
% \usepackage{caption}                   % loaded by apa6

\usepackage{setspace}
% single spaced tables excluding caption and table notes (set by pandoc variable)
\AtBeginEnvironment{longtable}{\singlespacing}
% NEED TO REPLACE: both hardcoded 1.655 values (double spacing at 12pt)
%                  with the \baselinestretch at the beginning of the document
\captionsetup{font={stretch=1.655}}
\AtBeginEnvironment{tablenotes}{\setstretch{1.655}}

\title{Full Title}
\author{The Author}
\shorttitle{Short Title}
\affiliation{The Institute}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\lipsum[1]

\begin{threeparttable}

% start of pandoc generated table
\begin{longtable}[]{@{}ccc@{}}
\caption{Advantages of Various Fruits}\tabularnewline
\toprule
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.20\columnwidth}\centering
Fruit\strut
\end{minipage} & \begin{minipage}[b]{0.24\columnwidth}\centering
Price\strut
\end{minipage} & \begin{minipage}[b]{0.32\columnwidth}\centering
Advantages\tabfnm{a}\strut
\end{minipage}\tabularnewline
\midrule
\endfirsthead
\toprule
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.20\columnwidth}\centering
Fruit\strut
\end{minipage} & \begin{minipage}[b]{0.24\columnwidth}\centering
Price\strut
\end{minipage} & \begin{minipage}[b]{0.32\columnwidth}\centering
Advantages\tabfnm{a}\strut
\end{minipage}\tabularnewline
\midrule
\endhead
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.20\columnwidth}\centering
Bananas\strut
\end{minipage} & \begin{minipage}[t]{0.24\columnwidth}\centering
\$1.34\tabfnm{*}\strut
\end{minipage} & \begin{minipage}[t]{0.32\columnwidth}\centering
Built-in wrapper
and bright colour\strut
\end{minipage}\tabularnewline
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.20\columnwidth}\centering
Oranges\strut
\end{minipage} & \begin{minipage}[t]{0.24\columnwidth}\centering
\$2.10\tabfnm{**}\strut
\end{minipage} & \begin{minipage}[t]{0.32\columnwidth}\centering
Cures scurvy\tabfnm{b}
and tastes great\strut
\end{minipage}\tabularnewline
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}
% end of pandoc generated table

\begin{tablenotes}
  \textit{Note.} A general note.

  \tabfnt{a}{Specific note a.}
  \tabfnt{b}{Specific note b.}

  \tabfnt{*}{Probability note p < .05.}
  \tabfnt{**}{Probability note p < .01.}
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following solution saves the document `\baselinestretch` and restores the saved `\baselinestretch` for the caption and table notes.

```
\documentclass[man,floatsintext,noextraspace,longtable,nofontenc,nolmodern,nosf]{apa6}
% man class option sets entire document at 12pt and with double spacing

\usepackage{lipsum}                      % only for MWE

% \usepackage{longtable,threeparttable}  % loaded by apa6
% \usepackage{etoolbox}                  % loaded by apa6
% \usepackage{caption}                   % loaded by apa6

\usepackage{setspace}
% single spaced tables excluding caption and table notes (set by pandoc variable)
\AtBeginEnvironment{longtable}{\singlespacing}
% save baselinestretch
\AtBeginDocument{\let\savedbaselinestretch\baselinestretch}
% restore saved baselinestretch
\captionsetup{font={stretch=\savedbaselinestretch}}
\AtBeginEnvironment{tablenotes}{\setstretch{\savedbaselinestretch}}
\AtEndEnvironment{tablenotes}{\setstretch{\savedbaselinestretch}}

\title{Full Title}
\author{The Author}
\shorttitle{Short Title}
\affiliation{The Institute}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\lipsum[1]

\begin{threeparttable}

% start of pandoc generated table
\begin{longtable}[]{@{}ccc@{}}
\caption{Advantages of Various Fruits}\tabularnewline
\toprule
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.20\columnwidth}\centering
Fruit\strut
\end{minipage} & \begin{minipage}[b]{0.24\columnwidth}\centering
Price\strut
\end{minipage} & \begin{minipage}[b]{0.32\columnwidth}\centering
Advantages\tabfnm{a}\strut
\end{minipage}\tabularnewline
\midrule
\endfirsthead
\toprule
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.20\columnwidth}\centering
Fruit\strut
\end{minipage} & \begin{minipage}[b]{0.24\columnwidth}\centering
Price\strut
\end{minipage} & \begin{minipage}[b]{0.32\columnwidth}\centering
Advantages\tabfnm{a}\strut
\end{minipage}\tabularnewline
\midrule
\endhead
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.20\columnwidth}\centering
Bananas\strut
\end{minipage} & \begin{minipage}[t]{0.24\columnwidth}\centering
\$1.34\tabfnm{*}\strut
\end{minipage} & \begin{minipage}[t]{0.32\columnwidth}\centering
Built-in wrapper
and bright colour\strut
\end{minipage}\tabularnewline
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.20\columnwidth}\centering
Oranges\strut
\end{minipage} & \begin{minipage}[t]{0.24\columnwidth}\centering
\$2.10\tabfnm{**}\strut
\end{minipage} & \begin{minipage}[t]{0.32\columnwidth}\centering
Cures scurvy\tabfnm{b}
and tastes great\strut
\end{minipage}\tabularnewline
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}
% end of pandoc generated table

\begin{tablenotes}
  \textit{Note.} A general note.

  \tabfnt{a}{Specific note a.}
  \tabfnt{b}{Specific note b.}

  \tabfnt{*}{Probability note p < .05.}
  \tabfnt{**}{Probability note p < .01.}
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```